# Integrate monaco-editor with Angular 6.2 app

Tags: angular, angular6, webpack-4, monaco-editor

I am unable to run monaco-editor in my angular 6 application. I am trying to use ESM version of the editor, but not sure how to integrate with angular. The sample ESM code uses webpack config and requires web workers to work. But i couldn't find any sample/direction to use the same in angular.
From angular 6 onwards ng eject is also unavailable.

Not planning to use ngx-monaco-editor or similar as those projects seems to be abandoned.

Any sample code or guide will be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried using ngx-mocaco-editor: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-monaco-editor  ?

Comment: I have used it in my angular application and it is working fine

Comment: not planning to use ngx-monaco-editor. That project looks abandoned, as it is still in monaco-editor 0.13.1 version where as latest is 0.15.6. Which has quite some new apis.